# Pass component state to sibling

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox component (Material UI) that works as I'd expect.  On Check/Uncheck the state updates within the component.  But when I try to use that state in the parent component I only get the default state.  Even after changing.  So my `MyParentComponent` doesn't seem to know the state changes within the checkbox?

I want to use the state of the checkbox to show/hide its siblings.

I feel like this should be pretty simple but I'm really confusing myself with it.  Any help would be great!

Thanks a lot!

**Parent Component**

```
    import Checkbox from "../Checkbox";
    import Component from "../Component";
    import AnotherComponent from "../AnotherComponent";

    const MyParentComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Checkbox />            // I want to use the visible boolean state here every time it changes
                <Component />           // To hide/show this component
                <AnotherComponent />    // And this one too...
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
```

**Checkbox**

```
    const Checkbox = () => {
        const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            checked: false,
            disabled: false
        });

        const handleChange = name => event => {
            setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
        };

        return (
            <FormGroup row>
                <FormControlLabel
                    control={
                        <PinkSwitch
                            checked={state.checked}
                            onChange={handleChange("checked")}
                        />
                    }
                    label="Set live date &amp; time?"
                    disabled={state.disabled}
                />
            </FormGroup>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

In the parent component you keep the state of the checkbox and pass it to the other children.

```
const MyParentComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
        const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            checked: false,
            disabled: false
        });

        const handleChange = name => event => {
            setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
        };

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Checkbox state={state} handleChange={handleChange} /> // Passing the state of the parent to the children
                <Component state={state} />  // Passing the state of the parent to the children
                <AnotherComponent state={state} />  // Passing the state of the parent to the children
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };


const Checkbox = ({state, handleChange}) => {
    return (
        <FormGroup row>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <PinkSwitch
                        checked={state.checked} // using the state from props
                        onChange={handleChange("checked")} // using the state from props
                    />
                }
                label="Set live date &amp; time?"
                disabled={state.disabled}
            />
        </FormGroup>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, makes perfect sense!!

Answer (score 1):

The react site itself has a [great article](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) on how to do this, it's called lifting state up (to the nearest component, in this case, the parent). You will probably have encountered this already.

In your case you'd alter Checkbox (for example)

```
const handleChange = name => event => {
  this.props.handleStateChange({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
}

<PinkSwitch
  checked={this.props.masterState.checked}
  onChange={handleChange('checked')}
  />
```

Then pass in to Checkbox the two props:

```
<Checkbox handleStateChange={this.handleChange} masterState={this.state.masterstate} />
```

Where this.handleChange() is the state handler in the parent, and this.state.masterState is the state in the parent.

The same masterState can also be passed to the sibling components, so they are aware of the changes made in Checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The parent doesn't see the state because the state is in the child.
Move the state to the parent, and send to the child a callback, which he can use to change the state:

```
import Checkbox from "../Checkbox";
import Component from "../Component";
import AnotherComponent from "../AnotherComponent";

const MyParentComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        checked: false,
        disabled: false
    });

    const handleChange = name => event => {
        setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox checked={state.checked} handleChange={handleChange} disabled={state.disabled}/>            // I want to use the visible boolean state here every time it changes
            <Component />           // To hide/show this component
            <AnotherComponent />    // And this one too...
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

**Checkbox**

```
   const Checkbox = (props) => {
        return (
            <FormGroup row>
                <FormControlLabel
                    control={
                        <PinkSwitch
                            checked={props.checked}
                            onChange={props.handleChange("checked")}
                        />
                    }
                    label="Set live date &amp; time?"
                    disabled={props.disabled}
                />
            </FormGroup>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than lifting up your child's state to parent. there's another option, which is `ref`

```
const ParentComponent = props => {
    const childRef = useRef(null)
    checkRef = () => console.log(childRef.current.state)

    return (
         <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
    )
}
```

If your child is in a deeper level, then probably should use context to avoid props drilling